# How to create a temporary uploaded file and delete it after a period of time

Tags: php, file-upload, temporary-files

Is it possible to store the uploaded file by `move_uploaded_file` to a directory and mark it to be deleted after a few minutes? I'm trying to make a temporary file stay on the server after a period of time then it will get deleted (only if it's not processed with) so when a file has been uploaded and moved to a directory if it has not been processed (don't worry about this part, this will be done by me) it should delete the file from the server.

There is no way you can keep the temporary file on the server (without using `move_uploaded_file`) so basically stored in the `tmp` directory on the server how can I keep the file when uploaded into the temporary directory (or moved to a directory) and "mark" it to be deleted later on if not processed.

I've tried to research how this is possible, but I have not found any type of questions/topics about how to create a temporary file to stay after a limit of time.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I do not want the file deleted after the script has finished executing after upload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

First use the usual move_upload_file function and keep the file on your server.

Now create a new php program to do this:

1. use the filetime function to determine the last edited time of the file. Thus you can check if it was processed recently.
2. Compare the date/time above with your deletion criteria.
3. Use the php unlink function to get rid of the older files.

Now run the above program as a cron once a day.

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic way. Some servers regularly clear out the files in the /tmp directory after a certain period of time, but the only way you could be sure is if you wrote your own cleansing script and ran as a cron job. (Or use the poor-man's cron and have your scripts trigger the cleanse check, a less reliable but sometimes viable method.)

You can either flag the expiration time for the files in a database or text file, or simply use the filesystem timestamp to check for expired files.

A more complex solution would be to move the file into some kind of cache like Redis where you can set an expiration time (TTL), but that would depend on what kind of data you are storing and is a somewhat esoteric solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have another method that I use. I move the file to temp location. After it is processed it will not be removed on a fixed time. Rather next time the script runs, it will remove all previously uploaded and processed files. This avoids the requirement of cron jobs. Eliminating a little head ache.